# Proving the fundamental theorem of calculus without MVT

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

In this question [Proof of the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290410/proof-of-the-mean-value-theorem-for-integrals), someone proves the MVT for integrals using the fundamental theorem of calculus. I have seen another proof like this as well:

If $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$, there exist a point $c$ in $(a,b)$, such that:
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$\int^b_a f'(x) \, dx = f(b)-f(a)$$
so:
$$f'(c)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int^b_a f'(x) \, dx$$
let $g(x) = f'(x)$:
$$g(c)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int^b_a g(x) \, dx$$

The proof for the first fundamental theorem of calculus, or at least the only one I know, requires the mean value theorem for integrals this can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_first_part), so the above would be circular.

Is there another way to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus without this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVT for integrals is not necessary for the first FTC. Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable and is continuous at $c\in [a,b]$. Define $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ as $F(x):=\int_a^xf$. We wish to show $F$ is differentiable at $c$ and $F'(c)=f(c)$.

For concreteness, suppose $c\in (a,b)$. Now, given $\epsilon>0$, continuity of $f$ at $c$ shows there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $t\in [a,b]$
\begin{align}
|t-c|\leq \delta \implies|f(t)-f(c)|\leq \epsilon.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
So, $0<|h|\leq \delta$ implies
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h}-f(c)\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_c^{c+h}[f(t)-f(c)]\,dt\right|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{|h|}\int_{\text{min}(c,c+h)}^{\text{max}(c,c+h)}|f(t)-f(c)|\,dt\\
&\leq \frac{1}{|h|}\cdot \epsilon|h|\tag{by $*$}\\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this shows $F$ is differentiable at $c$ with $F'(c)=f(c)$ (very slight rephrasing proves the cases $c=a$ and $c=b$).

Comment: But the theorem user716881 needs proven to avoid circularity in the question is the *other* FTC: $$\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx = f(b) - f(a)$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair umm OP's second link refers to the first FTC (the one I proved). Also, I just read OP's proof more carefully, and it is flawed, because it invokes both FTCs. OP uses $\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a)$, and also that every continuous function has a primitive, which is really a corollary of the FTC I proved (this is used in the very last line when letting $g=f'$).

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of calculus is not needed to prove the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, by the extreme value theorem, there exist points $u, v \in [a,b]$ such that for all $x \in [a,b], f(u) \le f(x) \le f(v)$. Intuitively, it is obvious that $$f(u)(b-a) \le \int_a^bf(x)\,dx \le f(v)(b-a)$$
For a rigourous argument from the definition of the Riemann integral, if $P = (\{x_i\}, \{t_i\})$ is any tagged partition of $[a,b]$, then
$$\sum_i f(t_i)(x_i - x_{i-1}) \ge \sum_i f(u)(x_i - x_{i-1}) = f(u)(b-a)$$
Taking the limit as $|P| \to 0$, the integral also satisfies $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \ge f(u)(b-a)$$ The other inequality follows similarly.

Thus $$f(u) \le \dfrac{\int_a^bf(x)\,dx}{b-a} \le f(v)$$
As $f$ is continuous on the interval $[u,v]$ (or $[v,u]$, depending on which of $u, v$ is larger), there is some $c$ in that interval with $$f(c) = \dfrac{\int_a^bf(x)\,dx}{b-a} $$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $ P=( \{ x_i \} , \{ t_i \} )$

Comment: I am just labeling a partition $P$. The partition consists of a finite sequence $$a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = b$$ of partition elements and another sequence $t_1, \dots, t_n$ of "tags" such that $x_{i-1} \le t_i \le x_i$ for each $i$. The definition of the Riemann integral is that it is the limit of Riemann sums $$\sum_{i=o}^n f(t_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})$$ of such partitions $P$ as $|P| = \max_i x_i - x_{i-1} \to 0$.